# using pinch in the webview android

Tags: android, webview, pinch

I have two questions:

- I find this code to use pinch in the `webImageView` but when I change `webImageView` by `WebView`. I obtain an error in the code. how I use pinch in the `webview`??

  ```
   // create the WebImageView object from xml
  WebImageView img = (WebImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_pic);
  // fetches the image in a background thread
  img.setImageFromURL("http://www.mysite.com/mypicture.jpg");
  // enable pinch-zoom abilities on the image
  new PinchImageView(img);
  ```
- When I add pinch in my code is that supported by all the mobile android or you should have a specific screen to make it work it.

Comment: "I obtain an error in the code." ... how is anyone supposed to know what's happening there? Please show code and an error log.

Comment: the error is not when I run the code. when I write image new PinchImageView(webview); I should change webview.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable zooming in a WebView by following WebView setting

```
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Also you can set the default zoom level by using ZoomDensity

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the referencing library of Nikko?
http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/wiki/PinchImageView